# Difference between annotation and extending EndPoint in Tomcat 8 web socket?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Tomcat 8 has support for web sockets. As I understand, we can use either annotation(@ServerEndpoint) or extend javax.websocket.Endpoint to implement end points for web sockets. Are implementations of end points in both of these ways are equivalent? Or do they differ in their usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just Tomcat implementation, this API is defined as part of [JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356).

To answer your question - **annotated and programmatic API should be equivalent.**

There are some (very very subtle) differences, which you most likely won't notice In general, programmatic API is more verbose and it might reflect more runtime changes (reading configuration from property file etc) and annotated API is more static and less verbose (so you can do more with less code).